# Reduced Row Echelon Form for an Arbitrary Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand the idea of rref and how to use it with real numbers. however, I wondered if it will be possible to apply to an arbitrary system of equations (no actual numbers).
for example, how should I go about solving (geometrically, finding the intersection of the two hyperplanes) this system of equations:

$$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 +...+a_nx_n = d_1$$

$$b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 +...+b_nx_n = d_2$$

or even finding the null space if the above system does not make sense:

$$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 +...+a_nx_n = 0$$

$$b_1x_1 + b_2x_2 +...+b_nx_n = 0$$

EDIT: I have tried to do the rref for the above matrices, but it becomes extremely messy extremely fast. is there a better way of going at it? or do I have to power through the math?

Comment: Anything you can do with numbers, you can do with letters, BUT you might have to split into cases in order to avoid dividing by zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did solve this eventually, and I thought it might be useful for someone one day, so I´m posting the solution:

without loss of generality, assume both hyperplanes path through the origin. i.e. $H_1:\{x:v^Tx = 0\}, H_2:\{x:u^Tx = 0\}$, where $v,u \in R^n$. define A to be: $$
  A =
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   v_1 & v_2 & \dots & v_n\\
   u_1 & u_2 & \dots & u_n\\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
since u and v are assumed to be linearly independent, it results that A has a full row rank. now again, without loss of generality, we assume $v_i, u_j \neq 0$, such that: $$i \le j \le n$$ and $$v_k = 0, for \ 1\le k \lt i $$ $$u_k = 0, for \ 1\le k \lt j $$ in other words, $v_i$ and $u_j$ are the first non zero elements if v and u (respectively), and $v_i$ comes first. then it is needed to be splitted into two cases only, $i = j$ and $i \neq j$, and then the space of intersection can be found through row reduction of the augmented matrix of A.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is:

Consider the following matrix $A$

$$ A = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc} a_1& a_2&\cdots &a_n\\ b_1&b_2&\cdots&b_n\end{array}\right]$$

and compute the Gram matrix $AA^{t}$ which is of size $2x2$ and the condition: $$\det(AA^t)\neq 0$$ at least will give you the conditions to have linearly independents rows. More precisely, (assume $n>2$) since $A$ is of size $2\times n$

$$ \det(AA^{t})\neq 0 \ \Longleftrightarrow \ A\ \text{is of full rank}$$

Recall that any matrix $A$ of size $m\times n$ is said to be of full rank if $\ {\rm rank}(A)=\min\{m,n\}$ (that is, $\ A$ has it's maximum possible rank).

In general:

Let $A$ be a matrix of size $m\times n$. You have two cases:

1. If $m<n$, then $\det(A^{t}A)=0$ and we use the following result to see when $A$ is of full rank:
   $$\det(AA^{t})\neq 0 \ \Longleftrightarrow \ A\ \text{is of full rank}$$

   2. If $m>n$, then $\det(AA^{t})=0$ and we use the following result to see when $A$ is of full rank:
      $$\det(A^{t}A)\neq 0 \ \Longleftrightarrow \ A\ \text{is of full rank}$$

You can do a similar analysis with the augmented matrix:

$$ B = \left[ \begin{array}{cccc|c} a_1& a_2&\cdots &a_n & d_1\\ b_1&b_2&\cdots&b_n&d_2\end{array}\right] $$

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but I'm having a hard time to see how it finding the determinant is useful in this case. for A*A^t, it gives a 2x2 matrix:
$\begin{bmatrix}|a|^2 &  a*b\\b*a & |b|^2\end{bmatrix}$

which the determinant of is |a|^2 * |b|^2 - (a*b)*(a*b) != 0. which shows that a and b should be linearly independent, but how would I go from here to find the subspace of intersection?

Comment: If you have specific numbers, I mean no variables, you can compute the rref of the matrix B I put above. When you have only variables you have to consider two cases: 1) rank(B)=1, 2) ran(B)=2.

Comment: I want to solve this for the general case, hence the variables. I assumed rank(B) = 2, which is the most interesting case, but I still had to go through all the algebra, that became very ugly. as @GerryMyerson stated, I had to split it to many cases. I feel like I'm missing a very obvious way of going about this